# Navigation bar in a container

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar

I have a container in a view, and this container is linked to another view, those views are part of the same Navigation controller, but the navigation bar is not displaying in the container (though, it is displaying when I switch to the view the container contains...)

Is there a way to display it ?
Thanks.

Here is what's currently displayed, I would like the navigation bar too in the white container on the first picture :)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi. Could you show a screeshot of what's displayed by your app ?

Comment: Hi again ! Tell me if i'm wrong but your `chatView` is a `tableViewController`, not a `navigationController` with your view as the `rootViewController` ?

Comment: @shinyuX No, you're right !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices :

- Embed a `navigationController` in your `containerView`. You don't want to do that since you'll be instantiating a navigationController just for show.
- Add a `navigationBar` in your `containerView`. This way, you'll show a navigation bar, and when your chat section is picked, you push your `chatView` in your mainNavigationController (like you are doing right now).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, I kinda like the second solution, didn't think about that.